# Regex that captures and removes HTML tags but not within quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

The end goal is that I am stripping all HTML tags, etc, from a string containing HTML markup capturing inline JS only. There will be only one inline JavaScript within the snippet being tested.

I am looking to have a Regex that removes any HTML tag EXCEPT those contained within quote marks (either ' or ") which may or may not have line breaks.

Example A (multiple lines):

```
<!-- ClickTale Top part -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
var WRInitTime=(new Date()).getTime();
var html = '<center>Test</center>';
</script>
<!-- ClickTale end of Top part -->

<center><!-- BLOGHER ADS Begin supplemental 970 ad -->
<script src='http://ads.blogherads.com/97/9737/970.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<!-- End supplemental 970 ad --></center>
```

Example B (all as one line):

```
<!-- ClickTale Top part --><script type='text/javascript'>var WRInitTime=(new Date()).getTime(), html = '<center>Test</center>';</script><!-- ClickTale end of Top part --><center><!-- BLOGHER ADS Begin supplemental 970 ad --><script src='http://ads.blogherads.com/97/9737/970.js' type='text/javascript'></script><!-- End supplemental 970 ad --></center>
```

Both become:

```
var WRInitTime=(new Date()).getTime();
var html = '<center>Test</center>';
```

Currently, I have created this PHP function which is almost what I need:

```
function remove_strip_tags( $str ) {
    return preg_replace('%</?script[a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>|<!--.*?-->|<noscript[a-z0-9]*[^<>]*>.*?</noscript>%m', '', $str);
}
```

This takes our example and produces this:

```
var WRInitTime=(new Date()).getTime();
var html = '<center>Test</center>';



<center>

</center>
```

So how do I strip the html tags that are not within ' or "?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Good luck!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: If a use case is restricted enough, like "just look in scripts" and "there will only be ONE script tag", etc., yes one can consider oneself lucky that the case was processable with a regex.  It's not a general purpose solution, though.  And it's generally best to ask questions like "I need to do X" _not_ "I need a regex to do X".

Comment: @RayToal I understand where you're coming from. As an html-parsing solution, agreed, it's not general-purpose. As a regex solution to exclude certain patterns, the form of the solution is quite general. Still looking for the "general purpose" piece of code that will compute square roots AND do my laundry. :) I'm sure we understand each other, have a nice weekend.

Comment: Indeed, and I do favor pragmatic solutions.  If a regex solution works then great!  The last remark was more for the OP; it's usually best not to ask for a particular kind of solution but it is better to state the problem, because sometimes people ask for regexes when `indexOf` is the best solution. And yes, understood completely and +1 for your answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you're aware that most people here would advise you use a Dom parser to parse html. That said, here is how you could do with regex if you had no other option:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~([\'"])[^\'"]*\1(*SKIP)(*F)|<[^>]*>~', '', $yourstring);
```

On [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/28), see the substitution at the bottom.

This problem is a classic case of the technique explained in this question to ["regex-match a pattern, excluding..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)

Here is our regex:

```
(['"])[^'"]*\1(*SKIP)(*F)|<[^>]*>
```

The left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `'quoted strings'` and `"double-quoted strings"` then deliberately fails, after which the engine skips to the next position in the string. The right side matches the tags, and we know they are the right ones because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

**Potential Tweaks**

The expression to match quoted strings is subject to tweaking. For instance, if you want to allow escaped quotes within the string, you can use beasts like `(?<!\\)'(?:\\'|[^'\r\n])*+'`

**Reference**

- [How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)
- [Article about matching a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)